# Should you remove outliers in a small insurance dataset?

Tags: distributions, model, outliers

### Background

I'm working on an insurance dataset that has 4,000 rows, and 30 columns. The target variable is the loss incurred by the customer for the given row.

The target variable's distribution looks like this:

[image: Histogram distribution of a customer loss target variable.]

All the models I build on this distribution predict far too high for most rows and I think the outliers are causing this. If I removed them the overall accuracy of the model would improve but I'm deliberately not capturing black-swan events.

### Question

Is it good practice to remove outliers in an insurance dataset with loss as the target variable?

Answer (score 3):

Any financial measure can be notoriously skewed variable. But one wonders on what basis you declare these to be "outliers". They look like perfectly reasonable and typical values from a skewed distribution. Conversely, barplot some Cauchy realizations to see what outliers can look like. If you remove those values, all you do is change a representative distribution into one which is *not* representative.

If you are using the arithmetic mean as a predictor, it will generally have a larger MSE for the central 90% of the sample than. The problem, then, is not your sample, but your estimator. Consider a geometric mean, i.e. log transform the value for anaylsis, and then realize that there is in fact an error distribution around the mean.

Comment: Thank you, what is a Cauchy realization? Are there many types of geometric mean? When I search it I'm getting that it's the square root of a product of values. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Removing outliers seems like a terrible idea for this data set. Like, it might make your company go bankrupt type of terrible. An insurance company should be fantastically interested in the extreme events.

I suggest using quantile regression and paying attention to the regressions on the high quantiles.

Comment: Okay, thank you for that insight! From a brief read around, it seems quantile regression is where you try and fit other measures of the dataset, for example the median. Is this right? I also came across a percentage difference measure as an objective function, and I felt that might be a better way to avoid the outliers overshadowing the rest of the dataset. What do you think of that method?

Comment: Yes that is right